# Sourcetree and staging changed files

Tags: git, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to Sourcetree. I have created my git repository and committed the files I mean to have in there (only a small subset of the directory). Then I have edited code and change some of those files.

Now I'm looking for the command that isn't there: "stage all files that are already in the repository that have been changed since the last commit." I shouldn't have to do this manually, and I don't want to stage any new files. Okay, so what's the right way to do this? Is it somehow happening automatically? I'm sure this is obvious to the initiated, but I couldn't readily find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody comes to this answer via Google like I did, apparently there has been a change in the default configuration of Sourcetree and now you have to select viewing the "staging" area:

[There's a menu next to file show filter where you can select to show the staging area, after that there will be a checkbox mark to select all of the files as staged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpElT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the pending files in Sourcetree:

[image]

Modified tracked files are marked with a yellow box with three dots, like my *a*. Untracked files are marked with a blue box with a question mark, like my *b*.

So, to add to the next commit only the modified tracked files, check the checkboxes for only the modified tracked files.

But perhaps this is what you mean by "manually" as being what you would prefer not to do? Then choose Actions > Open In Terminal and say `git add -u`. If you now come back to Sourcetree and Refresh, you will see that exactly what you wanted to have happened has happened: only the modified tracked files have been staged. Now make your commit.

Comment: `> git add -a
error: unknown switch `a'
usage: git add [<options>] [--] <pathspec>... `

Comment: Sorry, I meant `-u`.